# Identify HTML Element in Chrome Developer Tools Profile Snapshot

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I've got a memory leak in my web app.  It looks like there are references to HTML elements that are no longer necessary and I can see this in the Chrome Developer Tools Profile Snapshots.  How can I identify which HTML elements are being displayed in the Snapshot Summary view?  For example, in the screenshot below, I'm diving into an HTMLAnchorElement and I'd like to know which one that is.  If I can get the "className" or "innerHTML" values of the element, I will be able to identify it, but I can't seem to get the values. Anyone know how I can do this?

[image: Developer Tools Profile Snapshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but you might want to take a look at the documentation for finding detached DOM tree entries:

http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/heap-profiling-dom-leaks.html.

Comment: Thanks Sam. It looks like the key is to look at the "to window objects" on the top of the "Retaining paths" view, as the documentation that you linked to suggests.